# Node batch script with Mongoose : connection closed by app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

scratched my head a big part of the night on this piece of the code.
Actually I need to process users account' subdocuments in a batch style. For sake if brevity, I just put part of the batch that's supposed to work... but it's not.

`err: { [MongoError: Connection Closed By Application] name: 'MongoError' }`

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var dbURI = 'mongodb://localhost/testdb';

mongoose.connect(dbURI);

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ email: String, name: String });

var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema, 'users');

mongoose.connection.once('open', function() {

    console.log("Connection opened, starting batch process."); /// this gets printed to console

    User.find({},{},function(e,d){  // error is here somewhere & yes I got plenty of users in collection :)
        if(e)console.log("err:",e);
        console.log("doc:",d);
    });

});

mongoose.connection.close();
```

All suggestions are more than welcome!
Thanks

Comment: You are asking the connection to close. Asynchronous means that the proceeding lines of code have not yet completed when you are calling close. It should be "inside" the callback or not there at all.

Comment: As mentioned by Neil ^, this is not how you close the connection, In this code, after opening the connection (which is `async`), the control shifts to the last line, so the connection gets closed before your `User.find()` transaction can begin. So place the `close()` line inside your `User.find()` function after the `logs`.

Comment: yep, Niel is right. I'm too tired to even see that. would better get some good hours sleep before getting boring you with this. Thanks a lot to both of you. (Niel if you want a +, just answer the question & I'll set it as Answered :)